# Importing and showing a local KML file using Google Maps API and GeoXML3

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to write a desktop application using C# which Google Maps API is embedded in. For this purpose, I embedded a web browser in the application and using Maps API. I could use basic functionalities of the Maps API inside the application.

My purpose is to create a KML file on the fly and show it on the maps. The KML files are successfully created from shapefiles using GDAL. I checked their validity by importing them to the maps.google.com. The problem I'm facing is it is not possible to show KML files on local disk using Maps API. There is no way that I could upload those KML files to a public server that Google can reach. I searched on the web and found that geoxml3 could be used for those purpose but I'm not able to handle it. Since Geoxml3 is subject to same cross-domain download restrictions, I get the "Access denied" error when I try to parse the KML file on my local disk. How could I make sure that my KML document is served from the same domain as the containing map page? I'm pretty new to javascript so any help will be appreciated.

If there is another way of achieving what I'm trying to do(like importing the local kml file to Google servers on the fly,etc.), please tell so. Thank you in advance.

Ekin Gedik

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer to cross-domain issues (at least before recent browsers with CORS: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), which I have seen but not experimented with), is to use a proxy in the same domain as the web-page.  I'm not sure how that will work with a local file though.

You should be able to access a local file from an application running on your local machine, but I'm not sure if that would comply with the terms of use other than for development.

Another option would be to pass the kml to geoxml3 as a string and use parseKmlString method.  That would avoid the xmlHttpRequest.

Comment: One of the purposes of this application is to convert vector data to KML format and show it on the embedded Google Maps. So, any KML file created will be present in the local machine running the application. But I can't get GeoXML3 to work with local files, I still get the Access Denied error. Thank you for your comment

Comment: How are you referencing the local files?  Are you using file or localhost?  I usually test geoxml3 with local files on my local machine, just using a relative URL (don't remember if that works in all browsers or not).

Comment: I both tried a relative URL and file. I place my kml file to the location where the html(with geoxml3 js code) file resides and both tried  `myparser.Parse('0.kml')` and `myparser.Parse('file:///C:/pathtokml/0.kml')`. Both attempts are resulted in Access Denied error.

Comment: Which version of geoxml3 are you using?  The trunk is old, the polys branch supports polylines and polygons, the kmz branch is more "kml standards compliant" and supports kmz files.  If you are using kml files not kmz files, I would recommend the latest version in the polys branch.

Comment: I try to supply the geoxml3.js in the poly branch with giving the url as `http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js` and by downloading the actual file to the solution directory and giving the relative path on disk. Both resulted in the same error. The error in the script geoxml3.js is thrown at line 1063 which is `xhrFetcher.fetcher.open('GET', url, true);`. I think somehow I could not provide the KML file to the script or the html that calls it but could not find the reason.

Comment: Don't use "http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js", use "http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js" (or download the file to your machine and access it there).  It should work on a local file if you get the relative path correct.  Can you provide an example html file that exhibits the problem in a browser?

Comment: Ok, I think my problem is not directly related to geoxml3.js but to browser type. When I try to open the html file I'm using with Firefox, it works like a charm and shows my local KML file. But when I try it with Chrome or IE 9, it fails. Since I'm using a webbrowserctrl in Visual Studio with C# and supplying the html file to this control, this could be the reason. Are there are any browser specific things that we need to handle when using geoxml3?

Comment: The xml parser and xmlHttpRequest are the only really browser specific pieces of geoxml3.

Comment: I guess it is directly related to xmlHttpRequest part. I debugged the code in Chrome using developer tools and as I expected it gave the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for http". It is interesting that Firefox does not gave any error and works fine. I don't understand why it sees a local file in the same directory of the html as a this. Any thoughts? By the way thank you for providing such a great tool and help.

Comment: Looks like a [security decision on the part of the Chrome developers](https://www.google.com/search?q=XMLHttpRequest+cannot+load+file.+Cross+origin+requests+are+only+supported+for+http).  If this is only an issue for development, you can modify the behavior of your version of Chrome, if your users will be affected, then sounds like you might need to tell them not to use Chrome... or run a webserver as part of your app (not sure how that would be more secure).

Comment: Looks like [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58151) about it is still open, but also seems that the developers think it is a feature, not a problem.